# Async loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to python. I'm using the latest version.

I have a for loop that takes long to execute, and would like to run it in parallel to improve performances.

After some research, I gathered that `async.io` and `async for` is my best option, but I haven't understood yet how I can transform my for loop using this technique.

Here is my code:

```
def filter(my_list):
    res = []
    for _ in my_list:
        if check(_): # this takes a while to execute
            res.append(_)
        else:
            print(f'{_} removed')
    return res
```

How can I optimize the execution time of this program ?

The rest of the program should remain the same, meaning that calling `filter` should not change, and should return a filtered list.

Thanks

Comment: Whether you use async, threads or multiprocessing will depend on what *check()* does. Python lists are threadsafe so you can append to your list from coroutines or threads. However, if multiprocessing happens to be your best option (because, maybe, *check()* is CPU-bound) then you'll need a different strategy to build the list

Comment: `check()` is mainly a network call, but the call is made through a obscure library, so I want to treat it as a black box, if possible, and just consider it takes a while to execute. Though I can say it's not CPU-bound.

Comment: I would recommend multithreading in that case. See my answer below

Comment: I don't see your answer anymore

Answer (score 2):

## Async

unless you modify check()

1. to be an async function
2. use async libraries/modules
3. to be primarily io bound

you will not gain any performance from async. example of a valid async function.

```
async def check(item):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return item > 5
```

if you did have an async check function, you could do something like this

series version that takes 10s

```
my_list = list(range(10))
res = [item for item in my_list if await check(item)]
```

vs parralel version that takes 1s

```
import asyncio
my_list = list(range(10))
check_tasks = [check(_) for _ in my_list]
checked = await asyncio.gather(*check_tasks)
res = [item for keep, item in zip(checked, my_list) if keep]
print(res)
```

Note how while creating the list of check_tasks, we don't use await. This is because asyncio.gather takes in coroutines.

Also if you use time.sleep(1) instead of asyncio.sleep(1), both series and parallel will have the same 10s runtime.

If you want to limit the maximum async coroutines executing at one point of time, you can use an asyncio.Semaphore and modify check().

Example - if we want 2 in parallel at a given time -

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
async def check(item):
    async with sem:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return item > 5
```

which takes 5s

## Multiprocessing version

check is defined as

```
import time
def check(item):
    await time.sleep(1)
    return item > 5
```

our initial code that runs in series will be

```
my_list = list(range(10))
checked = map(check, my_list)
res = [item for keep, item in zip(checked, my_list) if keep]
print(res)
```

and the parallel version will be

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
my_list = list(range(10))
with Pool(5) as p:
    checked = p.map(check, my_list)
res = [item for keep, item in zip(checked, my_list) if keep]
print(res)
```

Pool(5) will start 5 processes here. Keep in mind that starting a process is expensive.

Comment: I don't know if the right answer is using `async` or not. My question regards how I can improve the performance of my code by using parallelism. Is it not possible to encapsulate `check()` in such a way that it becomes asynchronous ? My goal is to make `filter(my_list)` faster than before, without changing the code that calls `filter(my_list)` nor changing `check()`, of which I have no control (obscure network library), and I don't really understand why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @hagrid The idea behind async is (very roughly) that the await keyword signals to the interpreter that the current task is waiting for something to happen, and other tasks can be run. I don't think that can be encapsulated. The most reliable way of guaranteeing that your code is run in parallel would be multiprocessing, where each check() gets a separate process, I have added this to the answer.